# Find three or four comma-separated numbers with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string `*White 4,5,6 LOTE Jr. Service Learning Kick-Off (2017-10-6)`
and want to find a substring matching the regular expression `\d,\d,\d|,\d`, corresponding to any group of 3 or 4 numbers separated by commas, and if the regex isn't present, return an empty string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = "*White 4,5,6 LOTE Jr. Service Learning Kick-Off (2017-10-6)";
let re = /\d,\d,\d(?:,\d)?/;
let [numbers] = str.match(re) || [''];
console.log(numbers);
```

`match` will return `null` if it can't find the pattern; `|| ''` will turn that `null` into an empty string.

Note that I changed your pattern, since yours says "three digits separated by commas - or, a comma and a digit".

If you actually meant numbers as your text says, and not digits, then use `/\d+,\d+,\d+(?:,\d+)?/` for integers; if you need floats or complex numbers, please ask so explicitly (they're quite more... complex).